# Visual Studio 2017 VB.Net Office 2010 Compatibility Issues

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, office-2010, office-2016

I created a program in Visual Studio 2017 using VB.net, which takes form data and creates a Word document with an Excel graph. I am running Win 10 and Office 2016. I have successfully run the program on Windows 7 - 10 (32 or 64) on both Office 2013 and Office 2016. However, I need the program to run on a Win 10, Office 2010 machine. Any version of Windows with Office 2010 simply says the program/app has stopped running.

Per what I have found on this site and other sites, it appears that such a program can run on Office 2010 with a certain .NET version and Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime installed. Here is the link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx

I have tried installing these on multiple systems, but it seems to make no difference in the result. I used the Event Viewer to see what was going on, and it looked like there was some security setting preventing the program from operating with Word and Excel, but when I changed the security settings in those two programs per advice received elsewhere, I still got the same result.

My searching leads me to believe there is a solution, and a simple one at that, but it has eluded me. Thanks in advance for advice.

Comment: Possibly your program is written to target a newer version of .net and your systems running Office 2010 only have an older version installed. You could try compiling the program to target an older version of .net, or install the newer version on the systems with Office 2010. To compile your program to use an older version, right click on your project name in the solution explorer. This opens a new tab. On the left side of the tab window, choose "Application". Click on the "Target Framework" dropdown and choose the version of .net that you need. For Office 2010, I think it should be 3.5.

Comment: Your code might not compile to an older version, depending on which features of .net that your code uses, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: You are right, it should be version 3.5. I set the target framework to that and it still works on Office 2013 and Office 2016 computers, but now the program stops working even sooner. Earlier I could get my form to appear, but when I clicked the button to generate the Word document, the program crashed. Now it crashes simply double-clicking the icon. I tried both installing my program and just using the EXE file, and both methods yielded the same result. Even though it didn't work out, thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

My code worked fine on computers with Office 2013 or 2016, but some changes made from 2010 to 2013 lead some of my code to be invalid when trying to operate on computers running Office 2010. The Word code was fine, but the Excel code had three issues. Here is what they were and how I fixed them:

1. Office 2010 and before do not allow Excel data label width modifications, so I compensated by increasing the overall width of the chart.
2. The method FullSeriesCollection for my Excel Series was not valid for Office 2010, so I used the method SeriesCollection instead.
3. I had to put my variable for the Excel chart range above my variable for the Excel chart. I'm not sure exactly why this was needed, because it worked fine in Office 2013 & 2016.